# Can a single easement have multiple dominant tenements, or are they multiple easements?

Tags: florida, easement

In Florida USA, a single deed granted an easement for water access over a specific piece of land (servient tenement), for the benefit of approx two dozen specific lots of land nearby (dominant tenement(s)), the which had various owners and have changed hands over time.

When analyzing whether the easement is still in use, is it correct to treat it as a single easement and verify whether any of the rightholders are using it, or is it correct to treat it as one easement per owner, in which case active use would need to be analyzed per rightholder and would thus require vastly more work?

I am hoping that a single easement created in a single deed can be analyzed as a single easement for "active use" purposes despite the multiplicity of property owners within the prescribed range of lots to which the benefit of the easement was granted, but alas, in my extensive web searching, Bing chat keeps asserting to me that a single easement can indeed have multiple dominant tenements and be treated as a single easement, but when I check Bing chat's sources, they don't directly answer the question, and when I revert to Google searching, I similarly do not find anything addressing this specific question.  :(